# How to join an array within a anonymous function on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Suppose I have a XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Lists total="1">
  <Listing>
    <Rooms>Living Room</Rooms>
    <Rooms>Dining Room</Rooms>
    <Rooms>Maid Room</Rooms>
    <Facilities>Parking></Facilities>
  </Listing>
</Lists>
```

I wrote a JS code to:

1) Check if the field `Rooms` is an array
2) Yes -> join the array by adding `,` and return it
3) No -> just return the string

```
var rooms = $(xml).find('Rooms').length > 0 ? $(xml).find('Rooms').text() : function (e) {
        $(xml).find('Rooms').each(function () {
            e += $(this).text() + ','
        })
        return e;
    }
```

This code doesn't return `Living Room,Dining Room,Maid Room` for the above XML, anyone know what wrong with my JS code?

Thanks

Comment: When I'm running the code given it returns Living Room,Dining Room,Maid Room, what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code can be made much simple:

```
var rooms = [];
$(xml).find('Rooms').each(function() {
    rooms.push($(this).text());
});
rooms = rooms.join(',');
```